# Jquery - Return data from fail getJSON

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to return some data from a `.fail` event from a getJSON call but it doesn't seems to work.

What I'm doing is this :

```
function myFunction() {
   var promise = $.getJSON(jsonPath).then( function( data ) {
        return data;
    }).fail(function( err ) {
            var myVar = "blablabla";
            return myVar;
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Should it works ?

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't return anything. But my problem is more complicated than that. I am doing an offline website and if the call fail, then I fetch the data from indexedDB. 
That's why I needed to return something from a failure.

Comment: your code works fine.. whats the issue here?  check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jcw3z/

Comment: My promise variable is inside a function, and this function has to return a value. So it's either from the ajax call, either from the fail.

Comment: Is your problem that you're getting unexpected results in your return value?

Comment: Your function can't possibly return the value because this call is asynchronous... which means your code will continue running, and the deferred will run whenever the getJSON call is done (successful or otherwise)